# Ruby template if else statement

Tags: ruby, templates, if-statement

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <% if rad_win == true %>
    <%  @mywin = "Radiant Win" %>
    <%  puts "1111111" %>
    <% elsif rad_win == false %>
    <%  @mywin = "Radiant Loss" %>
    <%  puts "222222" %>
    <% else %>
    <%   @mywin = "Loss" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my test.html.erb I have the following code. I can see that rad_win is false,but that code block is not executed. i.e there is no `22222222`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What you need here is a `case` statement, not an `if`.

Comment: @tadman, `case` and `if/else` are interchangeable. It's all about preference.

Comment: @c650 In many cases `case` is more concise, especially when comparing against the same variable in every branch, something that is the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using ERB, which requires that any text you wanted displayed must be used with `<%= %>`

As such:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <% if rad_win == true %>
    <%  @mywin = "Radiant Win" %>
    <%= "1111111" %>
    <% elsif rad_win == false %>
    <%  @mywin = "Radiant Loss" %>
    <%=  "222222" %>
    <% else %>
    <%   @mywin = "Loss" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But don't set instance variables in your ERB template code! This ain't PHP!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `@mywin` is an "instance" variable, that is it persists outside the scope of this block, where `mywin` would not. Can't warn something about something they don't understand.

Comment: `<%= "1111111" %>` is redundant since you're outputting a constant. You can just do `1111111`.